# Getting a 404 Error for image Path with Javascript Random Image generator

Tags: javascript, html, css, http-status-code-404

Everything works fine locally, but when I commit my changes to GitHub I get a 404 Error for my random image generator.

Can anyone help me solve this?

[image]
The Files are all in the correct folder, absolute image path also throws a 404. What's causing this?

[Back End Site](https://github.com/danielle93/google-doodle)

Comment: you have `src="../img/corg5.svg" ` which should be `src="img/corg5.svg" ` for both those images

Comment: Thank you so much! I made the adjustments and all is good now!

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the "../" at the beginning of [your image URLs](https://github.com/danielle93/Google-Doodle/blob/master/js/scripts.js#L3-L10).